# sql to group sort and concat two columns into one text field

Tags: sql, oracle

I am stuck with some sql and need a bit of help...

I have the following source table:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
1       A       B
1       B       C
1       C       D
2       D       C
2       A       D
3       E       A
3       F       D
```

My expected outcome is this:

```
Col1    Txt
1       A;B;C;D
2       A;C;D
3       A;D;E;F
```

So, `group by Col1`, and then find all the distinct values for `Col2` and `Col3`, sort these and concat them into one field.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: Fix it in an above layer.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using oracle 11.2 or newer you can use listagg

```
select 
  y, 
  listagg(x,';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY x)
from  
    (select col1 y, col2 x from test_table
union 
select col1 y, col3 x from test_table)
group by
  y
```

if you are using an earlier version you could resort to this one (taken from an old post of the oracle-l mailing list)

```
select y, max(sys_connect_by_path(x, ' | ')) trans
from (
select y, x, row_number() over (partition by y order by x) cur, row_number() over (partition by y order by x) - 1 prev 
from (select col1 y, col2 x from test_table
union 
select col1 y, col3 x from test_table)
)
connect by prior cur = prev and prior y = y
start with cur = 1
group by y
```

This  is a sample script to test both of them

```
create table test_table (col1 numeric, col2 varchar2(2), col3 varchar2(2));
insert into test_table values (1,'A','B'); 
insert into test_table values (1,'B','C');
insert into test_table values (1,'C','D');
insert into test_table values (2,'D','C');
insert into test_table values (2,'A','D');
insert into test_table values (3,'E','A');
insert into test_table values (3,'F','D');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [`UNION`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/union.php) the columns `col2` and `col3` and then use [`LISTAGG`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/listagg.php)

```
SELECT Col1,LISTAGG(Col2,';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Col2)
(
SELECT DISTINCT Col1,Col2
FROM YourTable
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT Col1,Col3
FROM YourTable
)
GROUP BY Col1
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
select 
  col1, 
  listagg(col23)
from
  (select distinct col1, col23 from
    (select col1, col2 col23 from table 
     union all
     select col1, col3 from table))
group by
  col1
```